# Would Like Social Media Bar to Disappear on Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have my social media bar more left and off the page when the user scrolls down. 
[image: Example of what is needed]

I would only like the bar to re-appear when you scroll all the way back up the page. My desired effect is [similar to this.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll)
I would like mine to disappear to the left, and only re-appear when the user scrolls all the way back up the page. If possible, I would like to keep the JavaScript to a minimum and (mostly) use CSS transform.

My current code is this:

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.right = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #4867AA;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #E03B65;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #FF4500;
}

#filler {
  margin-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

    <a href="#" id="about"> &nbsp; Twitter &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>

    <a href="#" id="blog">Facebook &nbsp; &nbsp;  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>

    <a href="#" id="projects"> &nbsp;Instagram &nbsp;
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp;
      </a>

    <a href="#" id="contact"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Reddit &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <i class="fab fa-reddit"></i>
      </a>

  </div>
  <p id="filler">Filler</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Could anyone help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195730/hide-fixed-social-media-bar-until-scrolling-down-certain-length-on-webpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you could achieve this by adding the following CSS that applies when the menu is to be hidden:

```
#mySidenav.hidden a {
  left: -200px;
}
```

Next, you'd update your script so that the `hidden` class is applied or removed from `#mySidenav` depending on the scroll direction:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  var sideNavClassList = document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList;

  // When new scroll position is less than previos, remove hidden
  // class from #mySidenav so that it comes back into view, otherwise
  // apply the hidden class to ensure that it's out of view
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    sideNavClassList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    sideNavClassList.add("hidden");
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
});
```

Here's a full working snippet - hope that helps!

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  var sideNavClassList = document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList;

  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    sideNavClassList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    sideNavClassList.add("hidden");
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
})
```

```css
#mySidenav.hidden a {
  left: -200px;
}

#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #4867AA;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #E03B65;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #FF4500;
}

#filler {
  margin-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

    <a href="#" id="about"> &nbsp; Twitter &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>

    <a href="#" id="blog">Facebook &nbsp; &nbsp;  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>

    <a href="#" id="projects"> &nbsp;Instagram &nbsp;
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp;
      </a>

    <a href="#" id="contact"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Reddit &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <i class="fab fa-reddit"></i>
      </a>

  </div>
  <p id="filler">Filler</p>
</body>

</html>
```